# Why is whoosh commit so slow

Tags: python, whoosh

I wonder why whoosh is kinda slow with the following code. Especially the commit takes quite a long time.

I tried to use limitmb=2048 with the writer instead of the default 128, but it makes almost no difference. As per suggestions I tried procs=3 for the writer, which makes the indexing a little faster, but the commit even slower. Also commit(merge=False) doesn't help here, since the index is empty.

I get results like this:

```
index_documents 12.41 seconds
commit 22.79 seconds
run 35.34 seconds
```

Which for such a small schema and roughly 45000 objects seems a bit much.

I tested with whoosh 2.5.7 and Python 2.7.

Is that normal and I just expect too much, or am I doing something wrong?

I also profiled a little and it seems like whoosh is writing out and then reading in lots of pickles. It seems to be related to how the transactions are handled.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from whoosh import fields
from whoosh.analysis import NgramWordAnalyzer
from whoosh.index import create_in
import functools
import itertools
import tempfile
import shutil
import time


def timecall(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        start = time.time()
        result = f(*args, **kw)
        end = time.time()
        print "%s %.2f seconds" % (f.__name__, end - start)
        return result
    return wrapper


def schema():
    return fields.Schema(
        path=fields.ID(stored=True, unique=True),
        text=fields.TEXT(analyzer=NgramWordAnalyzer(2, 4), stored=False, phrase=False))


@contextmanager
def create_index():
    directory = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    try:
        yield create_in(directory, schema())
    finally:
        shutil.rmtree(directory)


def iter_documents():
    for root in ('egg', 'ham', 'spam'):
        for i in range(1000, 16000):
            yield {
                u"path": u"/%s/%s" % (root, i),
                u"text": u"%s %s" % (root, i)}


@timecall
def index_documents(writer):
    start = time.time()
    counter = itertools.count()
    for doc in iter_documents():
        count = counter.next()
        current = time.time()
        if (current - start) > 1:
            print count
            start = current
        writer.add_document(**doc)


@timecall
def commit(writer):
    writer.commit()


@timecall
def run():
    with create_index() as ix:
        writer = ix.writer()
        index_documents(writer)
        commit(writer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some sort of merging of segments happening in the commit; this also explain why `procs=3` makes things even slower (more segments to merge!).

For me the solution was to set the `multisegment=True`, as suggested [here](https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/batch.html?highlight=limitmb#the-multisegment-parameter).

```
writer = ix.writer(procs=4, limitmb=256, multisegment=True)
```

You can adjust your `procs` and `limitmb` as you wish, but consider that **`limitmb` is per procs!** (i.e. they get multiplied)

---

**Caveat**: there has a penalty regarding the search speed. For example:

- 10000 documents: 
  `~200ms (w/o multisegment) vs 1.1secs (with multisegment)`
- 50000 documents: 
  `~60ms (w/o multisegment) vs ~100ms (with multisegment)`

Very roughly 40% slower on my system on the `commit` only. I didn't measure indexing times, but `multisegment` is also way faster.

This might be the solution for prototyping. Once you know you have the desired `Schema`  and parameters, then you can set the `multisegment` back to `False`, and run it again.

so just to give a rough idea of th